# Generate random number from specific set of numbers as3

Tags: actionscript-3, random

I would like to create a random number between specific numbers,
let say I have the numbers 1,2,4,5,7,8,9 and I want to generate a number between these specific numbers. Is it possible?
pay attention that the number 3 and the number 6 should not be in the generated numbers. Only one of the written numbers should be in the equation.

Comment: So you want to randomly return a number from this set?

Answer (score 7):

What about:

```
var arr:Array = [ 1,2,4,5,7,8,9 ];

var rand:Number = arr[ Math.floor( Math.random() * arr.length ) ];

trace( rand );
```

Or even more elegant:

```
var rand:Number = arr[ ( Math.random() * arr.length ) | 0 ];
```