# Pick a random frame from one ranges of keyframes

Tags: actionscript

I'm trying to do a Quiz game with 10 levels. In one level there will be 6 frames. For example , level 1 is 1-6 frames , level 2 is 7-12 frames , level 3 is 13 - 18 frames... When the user move from one level to another (eg level 2 to level 3), there will be a random selection of the frames from 13-18 frames ..

how do i code it such that the random selection can be execute?

Comment: You can use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379360/generate-random-number-from-specific-set-of-numbers-as3/19379481#19379481

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm starting off this answer with two assumptions:

1. you are working with ActionScript 3 (for data-typing purposes in my code examples)
2. every level has the same amount of frames available

First, let's create a variable that holds the number of frames available in each level. In your case that's 6, but this can always be changed.

```
var levelFrames:int = 6;
```

Now create a function that will give the random frame based on a given level.

```
function getLevelFrame(level:int):int {
    var baseFrame:int = (level-1) * levelFrames;
    var randomFrame:int = Math.ceil(Math.random() * levelFrames);
    return baseFrame + randomFrame;
}
```

- `(level-1) * levelFrames` gives the base frame
- `Math.ceil(Math.random() * levelFrames)` gives a number between 1 and 6 to add to the starting frame

And just use it like this:

```
trace(getLevelFrame(1)); // this outputs a number between 1 and 6
trace(getLevelFrame(2)); // this outputs a number between 7 and 12
trace(getLevelFrame(3)); // this outputs a number between 13 and 18
```

etc...