# Random text generator in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to have a dynamic text field that will generate different texts that I specify. How can I do that? I am using actionscript 3

Comment: What code have you tried? What are some examples of "different texts"? Is it a finite set/list?

Comment: What characters should the results contain? Are you talking about English words or just random characters? When you say 'that I specify' does that mean you input a list of text and then get back random items from that?

Comment: You can use this example and instead of numbers put your strings in array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379360/generate-random-number-from-specific-set-of-numbers-as3/19379481#19379481

Answer (score 5):

If you want random chars try this :

```
function generateRandomString(strlen:Number):String{
  var chars:String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
  var num_chars:Number = chars.length - 1;
  var randomChar:String = "";

  for (var i:Number = 0; i < strlen; i++){
  randomChar += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * num_chars));
  }
  return randomChar;
}

trace(generateRandomString(7));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array:Array = new Array ("Apples","Bananas","Grapes"); //create an array of possible strings
var randomIndex:int = Math.floor ( Math.random () * array.length ); //generate a random integer between 0 and the length of the array
myTextField.text = array [ randomIndex ]; //put the random string in your text field
```

Comment: Tip: You don't need to `Math.floor()` if the result is assigned to a variable of type `int`.