# AS3: how to generate a random number between 10 and 20

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have been trying to generate a random number in Flash. I have been watching videos and copying them, but when I click the button, the number does not apear in the text box.

Here is the code I have written in an air ios game:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
//creating the  vars
var difficulty;

//listening for the play button to be clicked
play_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, letsgotoframe2);


//and after the listening what do the computer do!
function letsgotoframe2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(2)
    }



//listening for the easy button to be clicked
Easy_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,letsgoeasy)






//what  will it do when it is clicked
function letsgoeasy(e:MouseEvent):void{
    difficulty = 1;
   var rand = (Math.random()*20)
   txt.text = String (rand);
   gotoAndStop(rand);
}
```

PS:sorry for  the bad structure this is my first post!

Comment: What errors do you get? Does the `letsgoeasy` function get triggered at all?

Comment: It doesn't generate number between 10 and 20. For expected result you could use uint(Math.random()*10 + 10) .

Comment: Add trace(rand): to your letsgoeasy function, then call it manually: letsgoeasy(null); does it output the random number in the debug console? If so, the title of this ticket is completely misleading and your problem is probably somewhere else in your code (mouse/events etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you a number between 0 and 10(inclusive):

```
Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 )
```

Now, just add 10 to that and you will have a number between 10 and 20:

```
10 + Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 )
```

I'm assuming you want integers. If you want real numbers, remove Math.floor and change 11 to 10 (your upper limit won't be 20, though, I'll be 19,99 etc)

Comment: Offtopic: The great way to "floor" a number is "|0" , take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19379481/1206613

Comment: @Cherniv. If you just want to truncate decimals (actually, coerce to integer), `int(the_number)` is more obvious and readable. Using bitwise operators to force the coercion ( `>> 0` would do the trick too)... Well, let's say it's a creative way to do it. Not sure I'd call it great, though.

Comment: wait then how do i generate a number bettween 0-640

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will give you random integers between min and max:

```
function random(min:int = 0, max:int = int.MAX_VALUE):int
{
    if (min == max) return min;
    if (min < max) return min + (Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
    else return max + (Math.random() * (min - max + 1));
}

var r = random(10, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the composition of the timeline in your .FLA it will be hard to diagnose this issue you are experiencing because it seems that you may have a few things going on with your code that are contributing to the issue.

**Issues:**

1. Since the structure of your timeline hasn't been provided, I can't assume that you have properly setup the TextField with the instance name of `txt` to exist across your timeline from frame 10 to 20.  I'm simply assuming frame 20 would be the max since you asked us for random numbers between 10 and 20.
2. Calls to the `Math.random()` function produce real numbers, not integers.  So producing a random number without casting it to an `int` before using that value in a `gotoAndStop` as you have will be a problem.

So to remedy these issues I suggest the following:

1. Ensure that your TextField does in fact exist across your timeline from frames 10 to 20. This can be done in one of two ways. The first by looking at your timeline and ensuring that the layer that the TextField exists on, has frames between 10 and 20. Or you can simply check frames 10 to 20 to see that the TextField exists on those frames.  Again, without seeing your timeline structure it is very hard for us to determine if those piece is setup correctly.
2. You need to cast your random number to an `int` for it to be used properly in a `gotoAndStop` statement.

Here is your code, modified to fix the casting issue; however, you'll have to manually check the existence of your TextField:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
//creating the  vars
var difficulty;

//listening for the play button to be clicked
play_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, letsgotoframe2);


//and after the listening what do the computer do!
function letsgotoframe2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}

//Easy Button Handler
function letsgoeasy(e:MouseEvent):void{
   difficulty = 1;
   var rand:int = Math.floor( (Math.random()*11) + 10 );
   txt.text = String (rand);
   gotoAndStop(rand);
}

//Create listener for the easy button
Easy_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,letsgoeasy)
```